# mal performanse usando Mongoose en el methodo .find({ year: year}) de (11K documentos)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Buenas estoy usando un cluster dedicado de mongo atlas en el cual tengo una bbdd con una colección de users de mas de 11k documentos los cuales tienen un atributo `year` que puede ser 2017, 2018, 2019.

El problema esta en que desde una api en Node con Mongoose al hacer un query .find({year: yaer}) (con el year de la request) por ejemplo 2017 retorna una lista de aprox 4.0000 objetos que renderizamos en front, paginamos, ponemos filtros etc..

Basicamente dedidimos filtrar desde front para no tener que estar haciendo llamadas a la api constantemente si cambias los filtros.

El problema esta en que la api tarda mucho en retornar los 4.000 objetos aprox 11s. He provado de indexar el atributo year en mongo atlas de la siguiente manera

```
{
  "year": "text"
}
```

y luego desde la api el

```
customers.find({ $text: { $search: year" } })
```

Pero no mejora el rendimiento.
Alguien que haya tenido una experiencia similar me podría ayudar explicando como lo soluciono?? o es que estoy ejecutando mal la indexación¿?

pd: La instancia donde se aloja la api es potente.

Comment: No me parece muy acertado cargar todos los datos para luego aplicar filtros a los mismos, eso significa que todo el proceso lo realiza el cliente, con los recursos que disponga dicho cliente. En mi opinión, tienes la posibilidad de crear eatructuras de datos con filtros comunes en tu `backend` para tenerlas listas para cualquier petición realizada por el cliente, o dejar que el filtrado/paginado lo haga efectivamente tu base de datos. Será mucho más amigable como experiencia de uso. Si cada vez que aplico un filtro he de esperar más de 5 segundos, evitaré aplicarlos como cliente!!!. Saludos

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, de hecho estoy planteando "refactorizar". La experiencia ahora mismo no es mala eh. Simplemente la primera vez tarda en cargar unos 7s la lista pero una vez carga la lista, el cliente "cachea" los datos y en cuanto aplica cualquier filtro se filtran al momento por lo que la experiencia es buena. Pero me tiene obsesionado esa primera carga. Se eligio este "flow" de petición porque a mi opinión personal me pareció más logico esperar una primera vez 5-7s y sólo una petición a API vs peticiones constantes y a no ser que pagines directo en bd estarias haciendo el mismo .find()

Comment: Como dato curioso es que cuando tú haces esa búsqueda en el frontend necesito mostrar cálculos, sumas, medias (de todos los resultados de la consulta) etc.. Si lo pagino en base de datos es difícil hacer esos conteos. A demás si cuando en el cliente cambias los filtros, tienes que esperar los resultados 4s o 5s me parecía una mala experiencia de usuario. Pero me gustaria cambiarlo y poner esa lógica en backend, solo que no encuentro una buena forma de hacerlo en mongo. Se hace muy lento. No se comor hace por ejemplo coches.net (Que filtra en backend, para que lo filtren tan rápido.)

Comment: Si dispones de algun articulo o algo donde pueda leer mas acerca de alguna posible solucion te lo agradeceria, muchas gracias y perdon por la turra jeje